Call backgroundworker in static method
I creating simple permutation code using c# app. Now I want to display a simple progressbar. Now if the program execute I want to check if the background is busy else I call the backgroundworker and show how many percent remaining.
The code below I call when permutation code is execute.
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetPermutations(IEnumerable<int> indices, int limit)
        {
            if (limit == 1)
            {
                foreach (var index in indices)
                    yield return new[] { index };
                yield break;
            }

            var indicesList = indices.ToList();
            var subPermutations = GetPermutations(indices, limit - 1);

            foreach (var index in indicesList)
            {
                foreach (var subPerm in subPermutations)
                {
                    if (!subPerm.Contains(index))
                    {
                        yield return subPerm.Append(index);

                        //Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//for waiting..

                        //try
                        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
                        {
                            // Start the asynchronous operation.
                            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

Error image:
and this is the backgroundworker do work code.
private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
          BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

          for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
          {
              if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
              {
                  e.Cancel = true;
                  break;
              }
              else
              {
                  // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                  worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
              }
          }
      }

My problem is, I dont know how to call backgroundWorker1 inside in static method. Please click the image above to see my error.

Why are you using the ancient BackgroundWorker anyway, and not using Tasks and await, alternatively a Progress object?

You can't. The BackgroundWorker belongs to each specific instance of the form and static members are specifically not that. You would need to either make that an instance method or pass the BackgroundWorker in as an argument.

^^ which is what the error message says. Did you read it?
